# How to get the each class results seperately in multiclass confusion matrix

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, confusion-matrix

I have actual class and res class here - https://extendsclass.com/csv-editor.html#46eaa9e

I wanted to calculate the sensitivity, specificity, pos predictivity for each of the class A, N,O. Here is my code

Here is the code

```
from sklearn.metrics import multilabel_confusion_matrix
import numpy as np

mcm = multilabel_confusion_matrix(act_class, pred_class)

tps = mcm[:, 1, 1]
tns = mcm[:, 0, 0]

recall      = tps / (tps + mcm[:, 1, 0])         # Sensitivity
specificity = tns / (tns + mcm[:, 0, 1])         # Specificity
precision   = tps / (tps + mcm[:, 0, 1])         # PPV

print(recall)
print(specificity)
print(precision)
print(classification_report(act_class, pred_class))
```

Which gives me results like this

```
[0.31818182 0.96186441        nan        nan]
[0.99576271 0.86363636 0.86092715 0.99337748]
[0.95454545 0.96186441 0.         0.        ]
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           A       0.95      0.32      0.48        66
           N       0.96      0.96      0.96       236
           O       0.00      0.00      0.00         0
           ~       0.00      0.00      0.00         0

    accuracy                           0.82       302
   macro avg       0.48      0.32      0.36       302
weighted avg       0.96      0.82      0.86       302
```

The problem here is - I can not deduce clearly what is the `sensitivity, specificity, pos predictivity` for each of the class A, N,O.

Answer (score 0):

This might be quicker to explain visually:

[image: An array of four numbers and a scikit-learn classification report. Each of the four numbers points to another number in the precision column: left to right turns to top to bottom.]

By default the labels should occur in sorted order (for your problem: `A`, `N`, `O`, `~`).

If you want a different order, you can specify one with the `labels=` parameter. The following has two classes, and orders them by: `[3, 2]`

```py
from sklearn.metrics import multilabel_confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

y_true = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
y_pred = [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]

mcm = multilabel_confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, labels=[3, 2])
tps = mcm[:, 1, 1]
precision = tps / (tps + mcm[:, 0, 1])

print(precision)
print(f"Precision class 3: {precision[0]}. Precision class 2: {precision[1]}")
print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred, labels=[3, 2]))
```

Output:

```
[0.66666667 0.5       ]
Precision class 3: 0.6666666666666666. Precision class 2: 0.5
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           3       0.67      0.57      0.62         7
           2       0.50      0.60      0.55         5

    accuracy                           0.58        12
   macro avg       0.58      0.59      0.58        12
weighted avg       0.60      0.58      0.59        12
```